# How do I detect if I'm in a 'full screen' bash shell or GUI terminal window?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have some code in my `.bashrc` that sets the terminal window title using the currently running command and it works great in Unity, where the terminal is in a window.  However, when I'm logging in with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> terminal (whatever it's called), my prompt gets filled with garbage that is various escape sequences that set the (nonexistent) window title.

How can I detect from within a bash script if I'm in one or the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in a GUI terminal window, you are not in a login shell. And if you are in tty, you are sure in a login shell. To test these, you can use:

```
shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'Not login shell'
```

or, simpler:

```
shopt | grep login
```

Example to use in an `if` statement:

```
login_shell=$(shopt | grep login | cut -f2)
if [ "$login_shell" = "on" ]; then 
    echo 'Login shell'
    # do stuff in login shell
else
    echo 'Not login shell'
    # do stuff in non login shell
fi
```

Comment: Briefly, how do I test that in an `if` statement?  Running the command then `if [ $? ]; then`... doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: @NickT Simple: `if [ \`shopt -q login_shell && echo 'y' || :\` ]; then echo "Login shell"; else echo "Not login shell"; fi`

Comment: I ended up adding the caveat to lump SSH terminals in with non-login shells as PuTTY can handle the retitling just fine: `if [ "$login_shell" = "off" ] || [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ] || [ -n "$SSH_TTY" ]; then echo "full configuration"; else echo "skip retitling"; fi`

Comment: This is **not** a correct answer. Both proposed answers falsely return "Login shell" and "Login_shell on" in a GUI environment when ran inside a login shell started inside a GUI terminal window. Depending on why you want to detect this, a more robust method might be preferred.

Comment: Upon further research, I was not able to find a single concise and reliable way to determine whether the current environment is GUI based. Calling this answer incorrect may be unfair given than there are no correct answers. I still believe that using approach alone is insufficient and that other methods should be used as well.

Answer (score 5):

Can't be much simpler than this:

```
echo "$TERM"
```

if it returns "xterm" you are in a terminal window
if it returns "linux" you are in a virtual (Ctrl-Alt-F1) terminal

Comment: You should explain how to interpret the result

Comment: Exact values might be dependent on setup (especially on which terminal emulator is used).

Answer (score 1):

In a terminal window in an X11 session, the DISPLAY environment variable will usually be set (except some cases where su is used); this will usually not be the case in a console.